# consolidate multiple python list based on list values into one

Tags: python, list

I want to consolidate python lists based on values of list.

```
    [4, None, None]
    [None, 4.1, None]
    [None, None, 4.2]
    [4.1,4.2,4.3]
    [None,4.1,4.3]
```

to

```
[4,4.1,4.2,4.1,4.1]
```

I want to get result with list priority, If first list is not having value, then it check for second and then third.

Comment: Can you elaborate what is the logic behind the example you provided?
You want a way to create a single list from list of lists that each list will contain only 1 non-`None` value?

Comment: This might also be asking for something akin to the SQL `COALESCE` function.

Comment: Yes @Dror Moyal

Comment: An important question will be what should happen when several lists contain non-None values in corresponding positions, or one of the lists containse several non-None values. The example is too brief to clarify.

Comment: @Datadev
`lists=[[4,None,None], [None,4.1,None], [None,None,4.2]]

filtered=[x for l in lists for x in l if x is not None]`

Comment: I am assuming your result set is just trying to remove None. I am curious to know what would have been the output if the input was [4, None, None], [None, 4.1, 4.3], [None, None, 4.2]. Would you have expected [4,4.1,4.3,4.2] as a result set?

Comment: I would want [4,4.1,4.2]. I have updated the question accordingly. @joe Ferndz

Comment: @Dror Moyal - I have updated the question with more elaborated example.

Comment: Can you explain the logic behind your result set. I am unable to understand. I get the first 3 lines resulting in [4, 4.1, 4.2]. I dont understand how the last 2 lines results in [4.1,4.1]. Shouldn't it be [4.1,4.2]. I am assuming that the logic should traverse thru the array m times in an n x m dimension array and reset counter to 0 then check for values 0 thru m again as it moves down the array of n. In this case, it will go from 0 thru 2 looking for corresponding positions 0 thru 2, then when it reaches 3, it resets x position to 0 for 3 and 4. Thus x position becomes 0 for 3 and 1 for 4.

Comment: @JoeFerndz, from the description it sounds like the desired result is the first non-null value from each sublist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with a list comprehension and a condition:

```
ls = [
    [4,None,None],
    [None,4.1,None],
    [None,None,4.2]
]

[n for l in ls for n in l if n is not None]
# [4, 4.1, 4.2]
```

**Edit based on new info**

You can use the formulation `next(generator expression)` with a condition to get the first value from a sublist meeting your condition. For example:

```
ls = [
    [4,None,None],
    [None,4.1,None],
    [None,None,4.2],
    [4.1,4.2,4.3],
    [None,4.1,4.3]
]

[next(n for n in l if n is not None) for  l in ls]
# [4, 4.1, 4.2, 4.1, 4.1]
```

This will raise an exception if there is no good value in a sublist. You can pass a default value to next as a second argument if that's a possibility.

Comment: @Mark Meyer - Thanks for your answer. Actually, earlier example given by me was  brief. I have updated question accordingly.

Comment: great work @Mark. I was going to attempt the answer based on the new info fro Datadev. Your answer covers the ask. So I guess this question is answered. I have upvoted your answer.

Comment: Thanks @Mark. Used [next((n for n in l if n is not None),None) for  l in ls], in case all values are None.

Comment: @Mark - I have got little different requirement. User wants that if first value in list is None and other two have values, then that row should also result None. Example for that is [None,4.1,4.3]. Here user wants to have None.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is your input, but based on your description I guess it is list of lists.

The easiest way is to do it is to loop over each element and check if element in list is null or not and add it to separate list.

Something like this:

```
result = []
for (list in lists):
  for (element in list): 
    if (element is not None):
       result.append(element)

print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def consolidate_list(*lists):
    ans = [None] * max([len(lst) for lst in lists])
    for lst in lists:
        for i in range(len(lst)):
            if lst[i] is not None:
                ans[i] = lst[i]
    return ans


print(consolidate_list([4, None, None], [None, 4.1, None], [None, None, 4.2]))
# [4, 4.1, 4.2]
```

I think this is what you're looking for.